# Hadoop not starting after reboot. SCM authentication error in log files

Tags: oracle, hadoop

I have looked at the scm password in `db.properties` and it is the one that is in the generated file. I made sure my firewall is off and checked everything I can imagine. I am more on the Oracle dba side, but experimenting with Hadoop/Oracle integration. 
I tried to test the SCM password via `pg_dump -h localhost -p 7432 -u scm >/tmp/dump.log`
and when I pass the SCM password I get the "Password authentication Error". 
It looks like nothing had started after the reboot.

I tried `service cloudera-db-server start`. It starts, but crashes immediately after 10-15 section. The cloudera-scm-server log says

> scm: password authentication failed for user scm?

Why would that work after the installation and all of a sudden it does not anymore?
I was working on it for almost a month and then it stops.

Comment: One more thing: when I run hadoop fs -ls /usr/data for example I get Failed on Connection....hostname:8020 - I can ping the hostname with no issues...what is going on here.